# How do I add generic items to a generic ArrayList?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have an assignment which requires me to implement a generic priority queue from scratch, however I'm getting an error that I don't think makes any sense.

```
public class PriorityQueue<E> {
     private ArrayList<E> items = new ArrayList<E>(0);
     ...
     public <E extends Comparable<E>> void insert(E newItem){

       if(numOfItems == 0){
          items.add(newItem); //ERROR: The method add(E) in the type ArrayList<E> 
                                       is not applicable for the arguments (E)
          rear++;
          numOfItems++;
       }else{
            //INCOMPLETE
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the

```
<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

int his instance. You already declared it at class level, so you don't need the type parameter in the method declaration.

You can just declare

```
 public void insert(E newItem){
```

then it will compile.

Answer (score 4):

```
public <T extends Comparable<E>> void insert(E newItem){
```

Change the first 'E' to 'T', since the type parameter is hiding the original 'E'

Comment: Why would you add a type parameter you never use?

Answer (score 3):

In a PriorityQueue, all of the items must be comparable. Therefore you must put the comparable restraint on the class itself

```
public class PriorityQueue<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {
    ...
```

Once you have done that, you need to remove the type parameter from your method, as it only hides your correctly constrained class type paramemter.

```
    public void insert(E newItem) {
    ...
```

P.S.
You want `Comparable<? super E>` because you want the most general constraint that will allow all items (E's) to be compared to each other.